# Save post_parent in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I'm using the save_post action to save some meta data in a custom post type:

```
function my_save_post($post_id) {
    // is autosave?
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // verify nonce
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['metabox_nonce'], basename(__FILE__) )) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if ('book' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        $post_parent = intval($_POST['post_parent']);
        $author = $_POST['author'];
        $price = intval($_POST['price']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'author', $author);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'price', $price);

        //TODO: add function to update the post_parent field
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I modify the custom post type's post_parent field? As I understand, I can't use the update_post_meta() function because the post_parent field is not a meta field. Am I right?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`wp_insert_post_data`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) filter instead, which gives you direct access to the post's data.

```
function wpa_insert_post( $data , $postarr ){ 
    //do something with $data['post_parent']
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'wpa_insert_post' , '99', 2 );
```

**UPDATE:**

I added the following to your code and it's working:

```
function wpa_insert_post( $data , $postarr ){ 
    //do something with $data['post_parent']
    $data['post_parent'] = intval($postarr['post_parent']);

    //update meta data
    update_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'author', $postarr['author']);
    update_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'price', $postarr['price']);

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'wpa_insert_post' , '99', 2 );
```

Comment: And how can I save the metadata using this filter?

Comment: @user1991185 sorry, just getting back to this- it seems you've figured it out, yes?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and quick solution could be something like:

```
$wpdb->query( 'update '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts set post_parent='.$post_parent.' where ID='.$post_id );
```

and you might need to add the global $wpdb;

If you are not using the update at the save_post hook (like if you are updating the metaboxes of your custom post type), you could, instead, use:

```
  $bookUpdate = array();
  $bookUpdate['ID'] = $post_id;
  $bookUpdate['post_parent'] = $post_parent;

  wp_update_post( $bookUpdate );
```